# Sql Server Reporting Service Problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008

I have a assignment question.

```
How to integrate Sql Server Reporting Service (SSRS) with visual studio?
```

i know that when you have installed BI tools it's possible to create SSRS reports as a Visual Studio Project. I'm not sure about the answer to the above question. Can some one help me regarding this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BIDS` (`B`usiness `I`ntelligence `D`evelopment `S`tudio) is the Visual Studio shell, just without the language and related bits. Using BIDS you can design reports, reference a (SQL Server) data source, and publish to a reporting server.

Is this what you were looking for?